# openssl keeps signing csr with algorithm SHA1withRSA when csr contains SHA256withRSA

Tags: ssl, openssl, keytool

Please help... I am using keytool to generate certificate request with sigal SHA256withRSA and using openssl to sign the csr using self generated CA but the output certificate I am receiving is showing signature algorithm as SHA1withRSA. I have verified .csr, self generated CA and they all have SHA256withRSA and in openssl.conf file, there's no mention of algorithm so I haven't got a clue from where it is picking up SHA1withRSA and how to resolve.

**Commands I am running : -**

To generate Keypair

KEYTOOL -genkeypair -alias servercert1 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -sigalg SHA256withRSA -dname "cn=servercert1,dn=domain,dn=com" -validity 1095 -keystore server1.keystore -storepass *** -keypass same -v

To generate csr

KEYTOOL -certreq -sigalg SHA256withRSA -alias servercert1 -file server1.csr -keystore server1.keystore -storepass ***

To sign csr using openssl

OPENSSL x509 -in server1.csr -out server1.pem -dates -days 1095 -req -CA selfsignedca.pem -CAkey selfsignedcapvt.key -CAcreateserial -passin pass:caroot_password -extfile openssl.conf -extension v3_req -text*

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Here are the man pages of the OpenSSL utility: [`openssl x509`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/x509.html). Check out the `-hash` option. Here are the man pages for the OpenSSL configuration file: [`OpenSSL conf`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/config.html). It can be specified there, too.

Comment: Issue resolved by adding -sha256 in the last command used to sign cert. i.e. openssl x509 -sha256 -in ***